# loop in 2-dimension array in Python(list)

Tags: python

I am searching one particular pattern and remove the File. I have written following code and it is working file but I feel I can reduce for loop when I am trying to remove File
(except List comprehension)

```
rm_file_pat = ["*.abc*", "*.xyz"]
        rm_file_list = [ glob.glob(f_pat) for f_pat in rm_file_pat]
        for rm_file in rm_file_list:
            for _rm_file in rm_file:
                os.remove(_rm_file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten the `rm_file_list` using `chain.from_iterable` and then simply iterate over the list

```
import itertools
for rm_file in itertools.chain.from_iterable(rm_file_list):
    os.remove(rm_file)
```

Comment: Don't use map for a side-effect. The first version is better

Comment: @gnibbler Even I was reluctant to add the `map` solution, but considering the fact that OP wants to remove `for`, I just added that.

Answer (score 1):

```
from glob import glob
rm_file_pat = ["*.abc*", "*.xyz"]
for rm_file in (fn for f_pat in rm_file_pat for fn in glob(f_pat))
    os.remove(rm_file)
```